# How do you display the number that has the lowest and highest amount of duplicates in a list w/o using built in functions?

Tags: c#, list, random

I've created a program that displays 1000 (1k) random integers with duplicates its rng range is from 1 - 1000, with that I want to know how many times a specific number has been generated with the highest and lowest frequency and display it. Ex: 51 is the number that has been generated 50 times, which is the highest
(Note: I cannot use any built in function for logic building purposes)

```
{
        List<int> numPool = new List<int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        string uinput = "";

        int storage = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            // generating number pool
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                numPool.Add(i + 1);

            // generating 100 numbers
            Console.WriteLine("Generating 100 numbers (1-1001) with duplicates...");
            int d = 1;
            while (numPool.Count > 0)
            {
                int temp = 0;

                temp = rnd.Next(0, numPool.Count); // this generates a random index between 0 and however long the list is
                Console.Write("{0}\t", temp);
                numPool.RemoveAt(temp); // removes the index
                if (d % 10 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();

                d++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Highest amount of duplicate numbers: "); // this part should show the number with the highest amount of duplicates
            Console.WriteLine("Number of times it was duplicated: "); // this part will show how many times it was duplicated
            Console.WriteLine("\nLeast amount of Duplicate numbers: "); // this part should show the number with the least amount of duplicates
            Console.WriteLine("Number of times it was duplicated: "); // this part will show how many times it was duplicated

            Console.Write("\nWhat number would you like to show the frequency?: ");
            uinput = Console.ReadLine();
            storage = int.Parse(uinput);

            // from this part it should show the number of times the duplicate number has appeared according to the user input

            //Console.WriteLine("The number " + storage + " has appeared " + insert the amount of times it has appeared + " times.");


            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't really generate the number 1000, because it would have to be 1001. But it's totally fine if it does not generate it. What's important is to display the number that has the highest and lowest amount of duplications without using "ANY" built in functions.

Comment: Create an array of length 1000, initialize it with zeros. Then for random number n increment the array field a[n]. At the end the array stores which number was randomized how often. Run through the array and look for the largest entry.

Comment: I can only use a list for this one, its for a challenge of my own. If its not possible then I'll use an array @FlorianMetzger-Noel

Comment: You can copy the code from built-in function. .NET is open-source.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the list and pick one by one every number and then check if the number is repeated using a counter, when it finishes add the number to a new List so you have a list of already checked numbers that you can use
For example:
You have a List like this `[1,1,5,1,7,9,9]`
First you'll pick the number 1 and check every element of the list if it's equals to 1 and if it is then you increment your counter.
When it finishes you have to add the number 1 to a new list which we will call "alreadyChecked" just for the example and then we gotta have a variable for the minimum and another for the maximum and check if the counter is greater than the maximum and if it is lower of the minimum and assign it correctly.
Now for the next number which is again 1 you'll check if this number is already present in the `alreadyChecked` list and if it is you just gotta go to the next number and so on.

Comment: That's roughly the same as my proposition of using an array for counting how often each number was randomized while randomizing them, just more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Why no functions? Store the results in a table and use the SQL count(), and group by functions to give a count of every occurrence of any given number.  If you sort descending your highest counts will appear first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).